# Mailman newlist breaks, No template found

Tags: debian, mailman

after installing mailman on debian wheezy and running

```
newlist mailman
```

i get the Error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No template file found: 'emptyarchive.html'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was at easy as it comes, locale weren't generated. I removed the comment in the locale I needed in */etc/locale.gen* and executed:

```
locale-gen
```